# CodeSandbox — How to fix tsserver.js errors?

Tags: javascript, warnings, codesandbox

I am currently getting two error in CodeSandbox every time I refresh or start a new Sandbox. I tried many things to solve without success. Has anyone come across this and managed to fix it?

**Error**

1. VS Code's tsserver was deleted by another application such as a
   misbehaving virus detection tool. Please reinstall VS Code.
2. Activating extension 'vscode.typescript-language-features' failed:
   Could not find bundled tsserver.js.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all codesandbox cookies and refreshing worked for me.

Comment: How do I delete Codesandbox cookies? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome you can do this from your browser e.g. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site or use an extension like "EditThisCookie"